# SSMS - Add a custom button to toggle retaining CR/LF in output

Tags: sql-server, ssms, customization

I'm using SSMS v17 and am hoping this is somehow doable.

In my SQL Server DB, I have many tables that have `VARCHAR` fields that have, within them, CR/LF characters (multi-line text).

I know there is the setting in `Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results To Grid` for `Retain CR/LF on copy or save` and I find myself often having to toggle that on / off since, if I always leave it on, I can get bad outcomes when I try and copy from the grid into Excel if there are CR/LF characters, but, other times, I just want the data from a specific row and want to copy that VARCHAR with its included line-breaks, so then I need to toggle it back on, otherwise, I end up getting the cell's value as one, long line (line-feeds are removed).

So, the solution I'd love (but I'm VERY open to other suggestions if there are any) is to have a custom toolbar button for that specific command so I can toggle it much more easily than having to go into the menu bar each time.

My challenge is that I'm not finding that command in the list when I try and customize the toolbar. Does it exist or is there another way to associate a toggle-button to that command? Or, as I saidm I'm very open to other suggestions if anyone has any.

Thanks!!

Comment: These are already on the SQL Editor toolbar. And there are keyboard shortcuts for them. Text = CTRL + T, Grid = CTRL + D

Comment: Thanks, @SeanLange, that could work, but I usually pull back a set of rows and copy across from certain cells. With the "text" option, it really only works well if I limit the query to a specific cell result. Still good, just not ideal if there's a way to toggle off the entire `CR/LF` feature instead.

Answer (score 5):

**SSMS Boost** has that functionality. [Copy cell data from Results Grid 1:1 (preserving line breaks)](http://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-copy-results-grid-cell-contents-line-with-breaks)

> SSMSBoost introduces "Copy current cell 1:1" command:
>
> select cell you want to view/copy, open context menu -> "Copy current cell 1:1" and full data will be copied to clipboard - all bytes and without any modifications.

And the second one is: [Copy Results Grid data to Excel (as xml Spreadsheet)](http://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-results-grid-data-to-excel)

---

**SSMS Tools Pack** also has similar capability [Feature: Export To Excel](https://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=17):

> This feature does not require Excel to be installed and creates a fully functional XLSX Excel file. Export all result sets, one or multiple tables or a whole database to Excel.
>
> Saving the best for last, **the characters like newlines and tabs are fully preserved and properly exported** into correct cells.

Comment: Thanks, @Lucasz. Never heard f SSMS Boost before, so good to know it exists. Only issue is that that feature is only part of the professional, it seems, so it would cost $150 just to get that... I was truly hoping there was either something free / a way to do it directly in SSMS - It seems like it should be easy enough to do without the need for an expensive add-on....

Comment: @JohnBustos Yes, 2 years ago this plugin was  free :/ And paying 150$ you got a lot of things so you should really consider if it is worth it. From my perspective it is.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion, though!!